# How to make line id's on continuous order

Tags: line, numbering

I have a problem with numbering the line segments.

I need to make line segment id's that have letters according to polygon areas (got letters for line segments already) and number according to segment's order starting from 1 in each letter areas. Result should be AAA1, AAA2, AAAn, BBB1, BBB2.. etc. By getting the $id or @row_number the QGIS program counts all segments (even though I need to count the selected in right order).

[image: sample image]

For example in this part the numbering should continue after 28 as 29, not 82 like it now goes. Not numbered segments should get numbers 1..n running in order.

I wouldn't mind if there is a way to automate the whole process. There are several letter areas to do the job.

I have an opportunity to use Arcmap also if needed.